# When to use Ariba vs Roary or other genomics tools to call drug-resistance variants?

Tags: genomics, microbial-genomics

I have a large dataset of assemblies of bacterial *S. aureus* genomes (~1000, same species). I am looking at different tools to estimate the presence of drug-resistance factors such as *blaZ* or *ampC*. Though, using three different approaches, I get three different answers. Some of the tools I use are [Ariba](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29177089/) or [Roary](http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/Roary/) after gene annotation with Prokka.

I wonder what are the most reliable tools used in the field to recognize drug-resistance and virulence factors?

Comment: I think you are in as good a position as anyone to know the answer within MRSA. Ariba has the 'genomics clout', but I'm not sure they are you're standard @Soren. They are genomicists and today is data science, whether impact factor currently reflects that or not. Personally I'd use phylogeny as a starting point, but you know more than I, about ML training, parameterisation and testing.